# How to send alert when AWS ECS running more then 30 minutes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

In my AWS account some ECS task take few minutes to complete and some task take two to three hours to complete.

I needs an alert to be raised when any ECS task runs in AWS account for more than 30 mins.

Is any possible way to raise a alert?

Comment: Can't your application do that? It should "know" much it runs for.